# I got the the following error when I use a code:

Tags: c#

only assignment call increment decrement await and new object expressions can be used as a statement

```
    {
        HudElem INFO3 = HudElem.CreateFontString(player, "hudbig", 0.5f);
        INFO3.X = 740f;
        INFO3.Y = 170f;
        INFO3.AlignX = "right";
        INFO3.HideWhenInMenu = true;
        INFO3.Foreground = false;
        INFO3.Alpha = 0f;
        INFO3.SetText("^7type following" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "^2infoa ^7fast refill " + Environment.NewLine + "^2infow ^7weapon info" + Environment.NewLine + "^2tk ^7 throwingknife" + Environment.NewLine + "^2bb ^7 bouncingbetty" + Environment.NewLine + "^2cl ^7 claymore" + Environment.NewLine + "^2sc ^7 suicide" + Environment.NewLine + "^2riot ^7 riotshield" + Environment.NewLine + "^2stinger ^7stinger" + Environment.NewLine + "^2bindkey ^7refill" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "^2open close ^7menu" + Environment.NewLine + "^23rdoff ^7disable3rd" + Environment.NewLine + "^2loc ^7relocation");
        player.OnNotify("open_", (Action<Entity>) (entity => (INFO3.Alpha = 0.6f)));
        player.OnNotify("close_", (Action<Entity>) (entity => (INFO3.Alpha = 0f)));
        player.OnNotify("CLOSE_", entity => INFO3.Call("destroy", new Parameter[0]));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the error was occurring from these two lines.  It seems you are probably looking to do something more like this code instead.

```
 player.OnNotify("open_", (Action<Entity>)(entity => {INFO3.Alpha = 0.6f;}));
 player.OnNotify("close_", (Action<Entity>)(entity => {INFO3.Alpha = 0f;}));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write this:

```
(Action<Entity>) (entity => (INFO3.Alpha = 0.6f))
```

since `Action<Entity>` is `void`-returning, that means your code is basically short for:

```
(Action<Entity>) (entity => { (INFO3.Alpha = 0.6f); })
```

That is, your expression is treated as a statement with the semicolon automatically added. And while you can't use expression in parentheses as a statement in C#, you can use assignment that way. That mean the following will work:

```
(Action<Entity>) (entity => INFO3.Alpha = 0.6f)
```

For completeness, if your lambda wasn't `void`-returning, then those parentheses would be allowed. For example, the following works:

```
(Func<Entity, float>) (entity => (INFO3.Alpha = 0.6f))
```